# code error Not able to insert characters

Tags: c, arrays, char, int, spaces

This piece of code saves a 12 digit number. And a name "with spaces" but whenever I run the code it takes the `int` input but skips the name part. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){

    char name[20];
    unsigned long long int x;
    printf("enter x:\n");
    scanf("%lld",&x);
    printf("enter name\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);
    printf("name = %s",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you enter the value for `x` you end with a newline. That newline will not be read by `scanf` and left in the input buffer. Then you call `scanf` to read characters until the next newline...

Comment: Change `scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);` to `scanf("%[^\n]s",name);`. The address operator doesn't make sense with an array.

Comment: The question is tagged C++, but the code shown in C instead. The C++ equivalent would be to use `std::cin` and `std::cout` instead of `scanf()` and `printf()`.

Comment: @user0042 what good would it do to solve my problem ?

Comment: my bad @RemyLebeau

Comment: @Abadprogrammer It would save you from seeing results of undefined behavior.

Comment: `scanf("%lld",&x);` --> `scanf("%llu", &x);while(getchar()!='\n');`, `scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);` --> `scanf("%19[^\n]", name);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No need for the loop, just prepend the next format string with a space.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _a name "with spaces"_ The name beginning with space is questionable. :D

Comment: so , should I clear the Input buffer before entering the name ? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I meant like first name and a last name as in "some programmer dude" @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: So try `scanf(" %19[^\n]", name);` instead of `scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);` (However, "some programmer dude" is too long. :-)

Comment: It was a pun :( @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

After entering the value of x, `scanf` reads the newline from the input buffer.
You may use `fflush(stdin)` after reading the value of x, to clear input buffer.

Comment: 'fflush(stdin)' - UB.

Comment: thanks for this one. I don't have so much experience in c, in starting days of learning C when i faced same problem and after searching for solutions, i got this one, so i suggested this one.

Comment: I didn't get the point of undefined behaviour and it's reference to fflush ? @Martin James

Comment: You cannot legally call fflush on stdin - it invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not reading your input for the string is that it is taking the newline character as an input when you press `return/enter` after entering the `int` value. A simple work around is to put a space in the `scanf` specifier for the string.

`scanf(" %[^\n]", name);`

This will work fine.